# Mailserver simulation for contact form on website

Tags: php, email, phpmyadmin, contact-form

I realize that I need to use a mailserver so people can contact me, my question is, how can I set one up on my local machine so I can test it?

I have XAMPP installed with PHPMyAdmin and I'm just toying and learning with it.

Now, in my **PRODUCTION** server, what email should I use to send users comments to me? I'm really new and need some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I don't recommend you setting up a mailserver on your local machine just for testing.

Check out the PHP function [mail()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), it should be already configured and ready to run on the production server.

If you want to test if your script works, simply print out the arguments you would pass to `mail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your production server is running linux, you can use the sendmail binary or local smtp.